# How to solve while loop in array?

Tags: arrays, loops, while-loop

Hello could anyone tell me how to solve this one, it's so simple but I'm new in programming.

[image]

```
f([9,8,6,2])
```

Comment: the question is What does the function call f([9,8,6,2]) return?

Comment: Please see [ask]. We also don't do your homework assignments for you.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the function is looping through the given array `[9,8,6,2]` and adding the numbers together. It's essentially a sum of the values of the given array.

The var `s` is initially zero (0) (`int s = 0`). It loops through each value in the array and adds it to itself (`s = s + arr[i]`). As the loop continues, the value of `s` continues to grow.

Therefore, the returned value of the function would be **25**:

```
s = 9 + 8 + 6 + 2
```